# link to ios app in desktop browser

Tags: ios, app-store

I've an link to an app in apples appstore. It works well when following this link with an iOS device. But if I follow it with browser on my desktop (PC or Mac), it just leads me to the itunes page and not to the app.

With android apps it works better, I will be lead to the playstore app and can install it then to my android device.

How usually this should be handled for iOS apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each download of iOS app includes user's iTunes credentials, so directly, through web browser you can not download the app. Only redirect to iTunes web page or, if iTunes installed on your desktop, it opens the link to the app where you can download it.